# How to filter out records from one table where its id occurs in a column of another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 MySQL tables

tableRooms contains the rooms of a hotel

tableRoomsBooked contains the booked dates of the rooms

[image]

I need an SQL query that returns the rooms that have no bookings between 2 given dates. This is what I have got so far:

```
SELECT * FROM `tableRooms` 
LEFT JOIN `tableRoomsBooked`
ON `tableRooms`.`id` = `tableRoomsBooked`.`room_id` 

WHERE (date BETWEEN '2015-01-02' AND '2015-01-30')
....?
```

The query should only get the room_id 2 because room 2 has no bookings in this period.

What should my query be like?

Comment: `where date NOT between`?

Comment: Does MySQL use the NOT EXISTS syntax?

Comment: @MarcB where not between will also return room_id 1 because it has date `2015-01-01`

Comment: @McAdam331 You are correct. This will also return room_id 1. Dookie has given the answer that worked below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
   select * 
   from tableRooms 
   where id not in (
     select distinct room_id 
     from tableRoomsBooked 
     where date between '2015-01-02' and '2015-01-30'
   )
```

This will select the list of existing IDs in a sub request, then exclude them from the main request.

Anyway, you should change the name of "date" column, because "date" can be confusing as soon as it is a data type too.

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thanks! 
And I changed the date column. Thanks for the tip!